# Updating a table using 'Eclipse HQL Editor' gives error

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, hql

When I run the following query in Eclipse HQL editor, it doesn't work:

```
update TblAdmin A set A.password='1a23'
```

I get the error message:

```
org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException:Not supported for DML
operations[update TblAdmin A set A.password='1a23']
```

Other queries such as select statements are working fine.

Is there any option to execute the statement from the editor?

Comment: I don't understand the connection between "googled" (which would mean searching) and "they misunderstood" what your were talking about (which would mean you asked somewhere already). But anyway, all the error message is trying to say to you: The eclipse HQL editor simply can't execute any modification statement (DML = _Data Manipulation Language_ like `UPDATE` or `DELETE`), because he would need to use another API method for that.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke What i meant was ,I saw some related questions and  people had answered that try  @ Modify.Sorry for bad Grammar

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Thanks.!!

Comment: You're welcome. I clarified your question and fixed some grammar. There is no problem with small grammar mistakes, as long as you clearly ask _a question_ and say what you want to achieve. Your original post did not contain any '?' at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eclipse HQL editor can't execute any manipulation statement (DML = Data Manipulation Language like *UPDATE* or *DELETE*).

The editor was built to show a *list* of results for a query. But a DML update statement would just return one single integer, which would (beside the call of a different API method) require a different UI as well.